# How do I work out the chords in Rachmaninoff op 23 No7

Tags: harmony

In this piece Rachmaninoff's writing is very chromatic. It is very hard to distinguish what notes should be considered as part of the functional harmony and what are passing chromatic notes. I have attached a link to the opening page of this piece.

[Attached image of Rachmaninoff op 23 no 7](https://ibb.co/sRKkxsX)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're finding it hard because most of the passing-notes fall on strong beats.

The underlying harmony is this:

Cm  /  /  /  |Cm#7  /  /  /  |Cm7 /  /  /  |Gm  /  /  /  |

The next 4 bars almost repeat the first 4, but with the RH transposed down a tone:

Bbm  /  Bbm/C  / |Bbm#7/C  /  /  / |Bbm7/C  /  /  / |Fm  /  /  / |

||: Abdim5  /  G7/C  /  |G7  /  /  Ab :|| Db(add9add#11)  /  Db  /  |Gm6  /  Ab  /  |

In the third beat of Bar 10 the arrival of Ab is delayed by the suspended high note G.

The Db(add9add#11) in the penultimate bar is better seen as a suspension: Eb over Db.

If you were analyzing the piece you'd probably point out the slow chromatic descent, during the first nine bars, of the 'tenor line' (mostly the RH thumb) from middle C to the G below.

Answer (score 2):

You decide what is "counterpoint" and what is "harmony", and ignore the "counterpoint".

In the first bar right hand, F# G Ab G F# G (occurring twice) is just decoration around G. And the D is a passing note.

If other bars make harmonic sense following the same patterns, the complete the puzzle that way.

Also the long Cs in the left hand are not really the bass line, but a pedal point. So I would be more inclined to take bars 2 and 3 as Cm/B and Cm/Bb than as Cm#7 and Cm7. In other words the B and Bb aren't really chord tones either, but just the bass part (or the tenor if you prefer to call it that) moving chromatically.

Chord names aren't an exact science in any case, so don't get too hung up about whether details like that are "right" or "wrong."

When all else fails, go back to basics. Stop looking at the score and start and ***listening***.

Comment: I was just thinking. Would one possible way of working out which is counterpoint and which is harmony, be to figure out what the harmonic rhythm is;In the opening here it would be one chord per bar. Write out all of the notes and then stack the notes in to thirds and see which one makes sense in tertian harmonic writing, the other notes would then be judged as counterpoint?